# Nginx rewrite subdomain to subdirectory without changing the URL

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, conf

I've been using Appserv for a while and moved to Nginx for now.
When I was running my website under Appache I had this configuration in the .htaccess file in order to link the subdomain to the subdirectory.

```
#Redirect API subdomain to API folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/request/
RewriteRule (.*) /request/$1
```

I tried to add this configuration to the nginx.conf file to do the same:

```
location ^~ /request/ {
    rewrite ^/request/(.*) http://api.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

It seems like it doesn't work since I'm being redirected to the main domain URL.
How do I manage to do that in Nginx ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/request/` and `location ^~ /request/` have absolutely different meanings.

Comment: How should rewrited request be processed? Proxied? Serving static file? Something else?

Answer (score -1):

there are a few different ways of doing it, but my preference for being easy to read:

```
    location / {
        if ($http_host = api.domain.com) {
            try_files /request$uri =404;
        }
    }
```

[nginx documentation converting Apache rewrite rules.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html)

Comment: Better to use separate server block instead of if

Comment: @AlexeyTen how is this "better". The official documentation shows examples exactly like this.

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil. Also server block match domain name more efficiently than `if`